# XLPagerTabStripでContainer Viewに設定出来ない

Tags: swift

下の画像にあるようにContainer Viewに設定することが出来ません。
なんでなんでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
import UIKit
import XLPagerTabStrip

class HomeViewController: ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        setBarLayout()
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
        return [
            Storyboard.newArticle.instantiateViewController(),
            Storyboard.hogeView.instantiateViewController()
        ]
    }

    private func setBarLayout() {
        settings.style.buttonBarBackgroundColor = .white
        settings.style.buttonBarItemBackgroundColor = .white
        settings.style.buttonBarItemTitleColor = AppColor.main
        settings.style.selectedBarBackgroundColor = AppColor.main
        settings.style.selectedBarHeight = 2.5
        changeCurrentIndexProgressive = { (oldCell: ButtonBarViewCell?, newCell: ButtonBarViewCell?, progressPercentage: CGFloat, changeCurrentIndex: Bool, animated: Bool) in
            guard changeCurrentIndex else { return }
            oldCell?.label.textColor = .gray
            oldCell?.label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(15))
            newCell?.label.textColor = AppColor.main
            newCell?.label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントに従い、プロジェクトを作成してみました。

行った作業を順に列挙しますので、ご自身の作業と差異が無いかご確認下さい。

1. `XLPagerTabStrip(.framework)`をプロジェクトに追加
2. `Project`→`TARGETS`→`Build Phases`→`Link Binary With Libraries`に`XLPagerTabStrip.framework`を追加
3. `Project`→`TARGETS`→`Build Phases`に、`Copy Frameworks`というフェーズを追加し、`XLPagerTabStrip.framework`を追加
   (ここまでは、Podsやcarthageがよしなにしてくれるかも知れませんが、使っていないので解りかねます）
4. カスタム`ViewController`のクラス名を変更している場合は、`Storyboard`→`Scene`の下の[image: ViewControllerObject]を選び、一番右のペインを`Identity Inspector`[image: Identity Inspector]をクリックし、`Class`名を作成した`Class`名に変更する
5. `storyboard`で`Scene`の一階層下の`ViewController`に対応するソース(`.swift`ファイル）の`import UIKit`の次の行に、`import XLPagerTabStrip`の一行を追加
6. 上記`.swift`ファイルの`class XxxxxViewController: ViewController`を`class XxxxxViewController: ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController`に変更
7. `storyboard`で、`ViewController`の下の`View`に`CollectionView`と`Scroll View`を追加
8. 追加した`Scroll View`を右クリックし、`New Reference Outlet`の右の○から`View Controll`へマウスをドラッグ
9. `View Controller`が青い枠で囲まれ、選択されるので、マウスのボタンから手を離す
10. 接続先として、`Container View`と`View`の２つが現れるので、`Container View`にマウスカーソルを重ねてクリック

以上`Scroll View`から`XLPagerTabStrip`を継承した`View Controller`へ、`Referencing Outlet`を接続出来る事を確認しましたので、上記手順の中のいずれかが欠けているものと思われます。

[image: Referencing Outlet接続の様子]

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
TableViewの繋げ方については理解しております。
しかし、今回私が実現したいことといたしましてはXLPagerTabStripというライブラリについての質問でして
https://qiita.com/KikurageChan/items/35593dc3aac8d694db8e#storyboard%E3%81%AE%E6%BA%96%E5%82%9
上記のリンクにある設定をしようとしたものの出来ませんでしたので、質問させていただきました。

Comment: 失礼しました、それでは今のままでは情報が不足しているので、ホーム Sceneの下のホームのFiles Ownerのソースを質問に追加していただけないでしょうか？

Comment: ソースコードを拝見しました。可能性としては上記回答の3, 4辺りが怪しそうですね。